# Sum of array with given condition

Tags: java, arrays

The question is to print the sum of an array with the following condition:

> If the array has 6 and 7 in succeeding orders, ignore the numbers between 6 and 7 and consider the other numbers for calculation of sum.

Sample output:

> **Output**: 22 for [10,3,6,1,2,7,9] [i.e 10+3+9]
>
> **Output**: 19 for [7,1,2,3,6]
>
> **Output**: 12:10 for [1,6,4,7,9, 1]

My Code:

```
int sum=0;
for (int i=0; i<n.length-1; i++) {
    if (n[i]==6 && n[i+1]==7) {
         continue;
     }
     else{
         sum+=n[i];
     }
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

I am not getting the expected output. I know my logic is not perfect, but I don't know how to do it. So any help or guidance will be very helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: From your examples, it's not clear whether it should be greedy or reluctant. What should happen with `6, 10000, 6, 20000, 7`? Should it give `10006`, or should it give `0`?

Comment: I am not sure about your condition because they havent mentioned anything about repetition of numbers but how to satisfy the condition given in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done with nested loop looking for 7, although it would get tricky depending how we should handle nested 6 and 7. In below example 6, 6, 7 the middle 6 gets ignored:

```
int[] n = {1,6,3,7,6,6,7,1};
int sum = 0;
outer:
for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
    if (n[i] == 6) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n.length; j++) {
            if (n[j] == 7) {
                i = j;
                continue outer;
            }
        }
    }
    sum += n[i];
}

System.out.println(sum); // 2
```

Comment: How is it supposed to work if there are multiple intervals delimited by `6` and `7`, it doesn't have enough space to store their indices...

Comment: @AndreyTyukin improved to handle nested, but it's not clear in the problem statement.

Comment: I know that it's not clear from the problem statement. The OP himself admits that he doesn't know what he's asking, because *"they"* have not specified what's to be done. Fortunately, there is a close button for such cases, which I highly recommend for not getting stuck with undeletable zero-upvote answers ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
 int[] n = {10,3,6,1,2,7,9};
 int sum = 0,d=0;    
 for(int i=0;i<n.length-1;i++){
     if(n[i]==6){
         for(int j=n.length-1;j>=0;j--){
             if(n[j]==7)
             break;
             d=d+n[j];
         }
         break;
      }
     sum=sum+n[i];
  }
 System.out.println(d+sum); 
 }
```

Comment: Dont put the code directly. Provide explanation.  Go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to answer better

Answer (score 0):

```
    int sum=0,i;
    boolean add = true;
    int[] array = new int[]{1,6,4,7,9};
    for(i=0; i<array.length;i++)
    {

        if(array[i] != 6 && add==true)
            sum = sum+array[i];
        else if(array[i] == 6){
            if((i+1) == array.length)
                sum = sum+array[i];
            else
                add = false;
        }
        else if(array[i] == 7)
            add = true;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: Same as the other answers: Dont put the code directly. Provide explanation. Go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to answer better.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //int arr[]= {10,3,6,1,2,7,9};
    //int arr[]= {7,1,2,3,6};
    int arr[]= {1,6,4,7,9};
    int n=arr.length; //the length of the array
    int sum1=0,sum2=0,sum3=0;
    boolean flag=false;

    for(int i=0;i<=n-1;i++) {
        for(int j=n-1;j>=1;j--) {
        if(arr[i]==6 && arr[j]==7 ) {
            flag= true;
            break;
        }
    }
    }
    
if(flag) {
    for(int i=0;i<=n-1;i++) {
        if(arr[i]==6) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            sum1+=arr[i];
        }
    }
    
    for(int j=n-1;j>=1;j--) {
        if(arr[j]==7) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            sum2+=arr[j];
        }
    }
    int result=sum1+sum2;
    System.out.println(result);
}
else {
    for(int k=0;k<n;k++) {
        sum3+=arr[k];
    }
    System.out.println(sum3);
}
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It's something advanced. Here is the code for your problem.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] n= {10,3,6,1,2,7,9};
        int sum=0;
        int[][] x=check(n);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x[0]));      
        if(x[0][0]==6 && x[1][0]==7) {
            for(int k=0;k<x[0][1];k++) {
                sum=sum+n[k];
            }
            for(int k=x[1][1]+1;k<n.length;k++) {
                sum=sum+n[k];
            }   
        }
        else {
            for(int i=0;i<n.length;i++)
            {
                sum=sum+n[i];
             }
        }
         System.out.println(sum);
    }

    //function for if is 6 and 7 available in sequence and return that with indexex
    public static int[][] check(int[] a) {
        int[] x=new int[2];
        int[] y=new int[2];
        int j;
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
            if(a[i]==6){
                x[0]=6;
                x[1]=i;
            }
            if(a[i]==7 && x[0]==6){
                y[0]=7;
                y[1]=i;
            }
        }
        int[][] z= new int[2][2];
        z[0]=x;
        z[1]=y;
        return z;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    /* I have searched a lot for this . But never found the correct answer .
       Not even in this comments . 
       It will fail for some test cases .
        So , I have come up with my own code checking all test cases except 
       repeating digits .
       So , here is the perfect answer .
       Try this out . If you don't understand this , feel free to mail me
       @komandurimithra@gmail.com  */



    int[] a = new int[] {5,6,10,3,1,7,2,9} ;
    int n =  a.length ;
    int sum = 0 ;
    int extra_sum = 0 ;
    boolean first_six = false ;
    boolean second_seven = false ;
    boolean add = true ;
    for(int i : a)
    {
        if(i == 6)
        {
            add = false ;
            first_six = true ;
        }
        else if(i == 7 && first_six == true)
        {   
            add = true ;
            second_seven = true ;
        }
        if(add == false)
        {
            extra_sum += i ;
        }
        else if(add == true)
        {
            sum += i ;
        }
    }
    if(first_six == true && second_seven == true)
    {
        sum -= 7 ;
    }
    else if(first_six == true)
    {
        sum += extra_sum ;
    }
    System.out.println(sum) ;
```